# Dialogflow intent issues or bug

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Okay, I am trying to figure out why dialog flow keeps adding dashes or extra numbers when I call my bot and the telephony. I can say 6 digit number and it either adds a dash of an extra number. I have used all the sys entities and a custom entity and it does this every time. It acts as if it wants a phone number. Is there a fix? And yes I have added definitions of how numbers I want back. The number I was asking for is 813637 but it adds numbers and/or dashes. I can add the screenshot to this to show you what I get back

[image: response]

[image: result]

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question to include examples such as the Intent you're using that isn't working as expected and an example of the conversation that you're using to test it, what you're getting, and what you expected?

Comment: Updated the question with images

Comment: After the user speaks the numbers it adds the dashes and extra numbers. So in dialogflow training it shows dashes and extra numbers also it is in stackdriver logs and in azure functions console log. I have tried all @sys and added new ones. It still thinks it's needs to be a phone number. It works if the number is done with actions-on-google but telephony speak seems to break it. Also have seem instances of 2 being writing as to and 4 being writing as for.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Google documentation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities

The description of **@sys.number** says the input is represented as Ordinal and Cardinal numbers.

However, as per my understanding you require it to be a Nominal Number. Also in your case i understand it is a sequence of numbers. In which case you should try using **@sys.number-sequence**.

Hope this works for you.

Do let us know how it goes in the comments.